# HighCharts. How to display X axis labels line without data?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I can not draw a X axis labels line without data. This is necessary so that the height of the graph does not change due to the lack of labels. I solved this problem through chart.spacingBottom, but maybe there is a more correct solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/5z470jLb/

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
       formatter: function() {
          let value = this.value;
          let resultValue = value > 100000 ? value : null;
          return resultValue;
        },
        enabled: true
    },
    tickWidth: 0
}
```

[image: HighCharts]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions to this issue:

1) Set `xAxis.labels.reserveSpace = false`

**Demo:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1rch9d3b/

2) Set `chart.spacingBottom`

**Demo:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6zwoL2mf/1/

3) In the `xAxis.labels.formatter` callback instead of null return a span element with `opacity = 0`:

```
  xAxis: {
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        let value = this.value;
        let resultValue = value > 100000 ? value : '<span style="opacity: 0;">a</span>';
        return resultValue;
      },
      enabled: true
    },
    tickWidth: 0
  }
```

**Demo:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9m51hvgp/

Answer (score 1):

Basically, specifying the min/max will force the labels to appear even without any series that contain data.

Numeric example:

```
xAxis: {
  labels: {
    enabled: true   
  },
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  tickWidth: 0,
  tickInterval: 10
},
```

Categorical example:

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
            enabled: true   
  },
  categories: ['apples', 'bananas'],
  min: 0,
  max: 1, // = number of categories - 1
},
```